# compute number of pairs in a given array with a specific condition

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

How can we compute number of pairs (P,Q) in a given array, Q>P, such that C[P] * C[Q] ≥ C[P] + C[Q]  with complexity O(N) ?

Comment: What do you mean by C[P]? Is just a typical constraint?

Comment: C is our given array,P and Q are 2 indexes which P<Q

Comment: Is the array sorted? If the array is sorted, then i think a single loop should be enough, otherwise, it would be `N + NlgN` complexity

Comment: This Code Chef Problem code: [PROSUM](http://www.codechef.com/MARCH14/problems/PROSUM). I've solved it. There is a linear time solution. The competition is still ongoing for another day. If no one has posted an answer by the 19th I'll give mine. It can be calculated after a single pass through the array.

Comment: @anirudh no it is not sorted, but even if it was sorted, how would you count the number of pairs within one loop ?

Comment: Related - [Finding pairs with product greater than sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840175/finding-pairs-with-product-greater-than-sum), although that's a sorted array of floats (you didn't specify floats or integers, or whatever other possible type - note that you could more than likely use a very similar approach if you're dealing with integers).

Comment: @Dukeling Actually it was the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is impossible in the general case (for real numbers), but under some assumptions on the numbers, it is possible.

For example, consider the case of non-negative integers:

Let `X` and `Y` be non-negative integers:

- If `X=0` and `Y=0`:                    `X + Y = X * Y`
- If `X=0` or `X=1`, for any `Y>0`:      `X + Y > X * Y`
- If `Y=0` or `Y=1`, for any `X>0`:      `X + Y > X * Y`
- In any other case: `X + Y <= X * Y`

So we can run across the array, and count the number of `0`'s, `1`'s, and greater than `1`'s (this takes `O(n)` time):

We're only interested in combinations of pairs where both numbers are from the group "greater than 1's", or the group of "0's" (any other combination of numbers doesn't satisfy the condition).

Let's say the number of pairs in the first group is `n` and the second group is `m`, the total number of pairs satisfying the condition `X * Y >= X + Y` is:

`n(n-1)/2 + m(m-1)/2` (representing the number of possible pairs in each group).

This method can probably be extended to other classes of numbers (e.g. signed integers).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this as a straightforward programming approach with O(N) complexity as you have N^2 combinations to try.

Just do nested for loops performing the comparison and computer the results.

i.e.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i=0;i<len;i++) {
   for (int j=i+1;j<len;j++) {
      if (arr[i]*arr[j] >= arr[i]+arr[j]) {
         count++;
      }
   }
}
```

Note that I loop from i in the inner loop so each pair only gets scanned once.

It sounds like there is some "trick" algorithm involved that will allow you to get linear but that's a math/algorithms problem not a programming one and I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: Yeah, but this is with O(N^2) complexity. To be more specific, the exact execution steps are (N + 1) * N / 2

Comment: It is the old question in codility website:  https://codility.com/tasks/count_multiplicative_pairs/

Comment: Given the statement of Nuclearman would you please prove the first sentence?

Comment: Tim is accurate as far as checking every pair, but not every pair needs to be checked. Actually, no pairs need to be checked, but it takes a bit of work, math and logic to determine what actually needs to be checked.

Comment: @Nuclearman: Obviously it's all about math specially given the constraints but the problem is as is.

Comment: Fair enough, seems Ron posted a solution basically the same as I used, but I used 2 as a cutoff rather than 1 resulting in a more simple equation and no need to keep a count of the elements in the second group. I'll still refrain from posting the code due to contest rules until the 19th.

Answer (score 0):

I am not math-brain myself but i see a pattern here.
you didn't included it here, but there is assumption that is really helping here.

- array is sorted in non-decreasing order
- P

  if out >= 1 000 000 000 return 1 000 000 000

  (tip) if pair (x,y) is good, any next pair from this row is good (x, y+1) (x, y+n) you just need to find the first one. Why? look how plots from (x+y) and (x*y) looks like...
  there is joint point after which every next pair will work.

Look at example:
[lets assume natural numbers] like that: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8... will give u pairs :

- - pairs are (x,y) -> [ (A[x]*A[y]) >= (A[x]+A[y]) ]
- none for x == 1 :
- - ( parallel plots a+b and a*b for a=1 and a=0, no matter b),
- A[y] == 3 or more for A[x] == 2 (y=2 break condition y>x)
- A[y] == 4 or more for A[x] == 3 etc

---

**here I posted my code, it scored 45% so its not so bad.**

**I hope someone will catch up my idea and somehow improve this. Good luck :).**

```
inline double real (std::vector<int> &A, std::vector<int> &B, int i)
{
    return (double)((double)A[i] + ((double)B[i]/1000000));
}

int solution(std::vector<int> &A, std::vector<int> &B)
{
    int size = A.size();
    int pairs = 0;
    if (size < 2) return pairs;

    for(int x = 0; x<size; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = x+1; y<size; ++y)
        {
            double lx = real(A,B,x);
            double ly = real(A,B,y);
            double m = lx*ly;
            double a = lx+ly;
            if(m<a) continue;
            pairs+=(size-y);
            if (pairs >= 1000000000) return 1000000000
            break;
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```